# Why pixi.js tries to load node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, requirejs

I am totally new to JavaScript/TypeScript/HTML. Trying to implement a pixi.js "bunny" tutorial but with TypeScript:

app.ts:

```
/// <reference path="./pixi.js.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="./require.d.ts"/>
import PIXI = require( "pixi.js" );
... further Greeter/bunny code ...
```

and index.html:

```
...
<script data-main="app.js" src="require.js"></script>
...
```

and get HTML error: Script error for "node.js".

As I know, "node.js" is something about implementing server-side applications. Don't know if I should even try fixing this error because why it even tries to load?

Comment: PIXI doesn't work very well with require. On top of that, yes, you should search for "node.js" in your project files and paste it here so we can see what's going on.

Comment: @TheMatrixISReal ehm, I don't have "node.js" in my project files. All I have is "app.css" automatically generated by VisualStudio2015; app.ts where I have tutorial "Greeter" code; pixi.js.d.ts and pixi.js download from NET.